# Linux terminal communication with server

Tags: linux, sockets, terminal, websocket, netcat

I have a script that runs in the terminal that polls a server every 2 seconds for a 0 or a 1 from a PHP script, and then executes a command based on the result.

Unimportant note: it's running on a raspberry pi.

So my question is: Is there a better way to communicate with the server?
What would be ideal is something like a socket.io or html5 websocket type of connection, but thos specifically aren't doable from the terminal.

Here is what I have so that you get the gist

```
while :
 do

gpio mode 0 out
gpio mode 7 out

var1=$(curl http://url.com/index.php)
L1=$(echo $var1 | cut -c1-1)
L7=$(echo $var1 | cut -c7-7)
if [ $L1 == 0 ]; then
gpio write 0 0
elif [ $L1 == 1 ]; then
gpio write 0 1
fi

if [ $L7 == 0 ]; then
gpio write 7 0
elif [ $L7 == 1 ]; then
gpio write 7 1
fi

gpio readall
sleep 2

done
```

EDIT: I need to run around 1000 raspberry pi units using this on the same server, and i'm just looking for the most efficient method.

Comment: How would you define "better"? What criteria do you have in mind?

Comment: Why don't you like your solution? If you want things like persistent connections or similar, I'd suggest to use a more potent language. (Python for example). PS: please provide the Tag for the language you are using: [sh] or [bash]

Comment: `curl` is probably the best solution for this.  You could use `netcat`, but then you'd have to implement all the HTTP protocol yourself, and `curl` takes care of that for you. How much simpler could it get than what you've written?

Comment: It's possible that my method is fine, but after using sockets with an open connection (in my web dev) it seems heavy. I need to run around 1000 raspberry pi units using this, and i'm just looking for the most efficient method. If everyone on here agrees that this is ok for large scale then i'm good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this. HTTP isn't the best suited protocoll for this (since it doesn't support sessions), but since you're already using it. Let's look at a solution for HTTP.

Instead of polling (which is expensive but simple to implement) you can push data from the server to the clients.

For doing this with HTTP, use COMET that is an umbrella term for a few different techiniques for doing this. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Doing this with nginx you need an extra module, for example:
https://github.com/wandenberg/nginx-push-stream-module